# Gaussian process - Hölder continous paths

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation, covariance, levy-processes

Let $(X_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}_+}$ be a centered Gaussian process and $\Gamma:\mathbb{R}^2_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ the Covariance function with the following feature

$\Gamma(s,s)+\Gamma(t,t)-2\Gamma(s,t)\leq C(t-s)^\nu$       $~~~~~~~~~(\star)$

for $t\geq s\geq 0 $ with independent Constants $C,\nu >0$.

**I got to prove the following statement**:

Show that there exists a Version of $(X_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}_+}$ with Hölder continous paths and identify the Hölder-exponents.

**My idea**:

Apply the Kolmogorov-Chentsov-Theorem, but i have no clue to use the feature $(\star)$.

The left hand side of $(\star)$ is obviously $\mathbb{Var}[X_t,X_s]$.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: $(\star)$ can be used to compute $\mathbb E\left|X_t-X_s\right|^\gamma  $ for a fixed constant $\gamma$. Indeed, $X_t-X_s$ is Gaussian, centered, and we have a bound for its variance.  For a Gaussian centered process, a bound on the variance entails a good  bound on the moments.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Thank you for your help, I have come to this steps: $\mathbb{E}|X_t-X_s|^\gamma =\mathbb{E}|X_{t-s}|^\gamma$ and $X_{t-s}$ is, as you said gaussian and centered. specificly need now is a good ineqaulity fpr the $\gamma$-th moment of $X_{t-s}$. Can you show it me?

Comment: The assumption gives you an inequality for the second moment of $X_t - X_s$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Kolmogorov-Chentsov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_continuity_theorem) states that if for any $T\gt 0$, there exists $\alpha,\beta$ and $C\gt 0$ such that for any $s,t\in [0,T ]$, 
$$ \tag{1} \mathbb E \left |X_t-X_s\right|^ \alpha \leqslant C \left|t-s\right |^ {1+\beta} , $$ 
then there exists a modification of $\left(X_t\right)_{t\in\mathbb R_+}$ whose paths are $\gamma$-Hölder continuous for each $0\lt\gamma\lt\beta/\alpha$.

Let us see which $\alpha$ and $\beta$ satisfy (1). We know that $X_t-X_s$ is Gaussian and centered. Let us denote by $\sigma_{s,t}^2$ its variance. Then $X_t-X_s \sim \sigma_{s,t}N$, where $N$ is standard Gaussian. Therefore, for each positive $\alpha$, 
$$\mathbb E \left |X_t-X_s\right|^ \alpha=\sigma_ {s,t }^{\alpha}\mathbb E \left |N \right |^\alpha.$$
By $( \star)$, $ \sigma_{s,t}\leqslant C^{1/2}  \left|t-s\right |^{  \eta/2} $ hence 
$$\mathbb E \left |X_t-X_s\right|^ \alpha\leqslant C'\left|t-s\right |^{ \alpha \eta/2}$$
for some constant $C'$ independent of $s$ and $t$.
Thus $(1)$ is satisfied for $\beta$ such that $1+\beta= \alpha \eta/2$, that is, $\beta= \alpha \eta/2-1$.

Comment: But $E \left |N \right |^\alpha$ isn't necesarrily $1$?!

Comment: Or do you mean $\mathbb E \left |X_t-X_s\right|^ \alpha\leqslant C^{\alpha/2}\left|t-s\right |^{ \alpha \eta/2} E \left |N \right |^\alpha = C_0^{\alpha/2}\left|t-s\right |^{ \alpha \eta/2}$. So your first $C$ isn't the same as your second $C$?

Comment: @Frodo361 Yes I should use an other name.